# Buildroot compile error - Maybe you need to increase the filesystem size (BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_SIZE)

Tags: c++, c, linux, compilation, buildroot

Appreciate help if anyone have insight how to fix following compile error for buildroot that I have been struggling for almost a week.

I used following commands to pull buildroot repo and have tried this multiple times. I am using arm64 default config and before make enabling following flags

```
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_CPIO=y
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_GETTY=y
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_GETTY_PORT=”ttyAMA0″
```

After compile starts

```
git clone git://git.buildroot.net/buildroot
make qemu_aarch64_virt_defconfig
make
```

I see following error

```
mke2fs 1.46.3 (27-Jul-2021)
mkfs.ext4: No such file or directory while trying to determine filesystem size
*** Maybe you need to increase the filesystem size (BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_SIZE)
fs/ext2/ext2.mk:46: recipe for target '/home/jn4/linux-buildroot/buildroot/output/images/rootfs.ext2' failed
make[1]: *** [/home/jn4/linux-buildroot/buildroot/output/images/rootfs.ext2] Error 1
Makefile:84: recipe for target '_all' failed
make: *** [_all] Error 2
```

To change file system size I have tried modifying following parameter in .config file

```
BR2_TARGET_ROOTFS_EXT2_SIZE="250M"
```

I have tried many sizes - 60M, 120M, 250M, 256M, 512M, 1024M, however all have failed to compile with same error. This seems like a common problem with buildroot and there are few other posts in git or other places which recommends size of 250M to solve the problem. I continue to see compile error with many sizes I have tried.

Appreciate any insight since I am stuck at this point. Thank you.